# Can I use is_expected with block matchers?

Tags: rspec

The `raise_error` is a matcher that supports block expectations.

Below I have a spec testing that the `foo` method raises an error:

```
require 'rspec'
def foo
   raise StandardError
end

describe 'foo' do
    subject{ foo }
    specify{ expect{ subject }.to raise_error }
    it{ is_expected.to raise_error }
end
```

Now, `specify{ expect{ foo }.to raise_error }` passes as expected, but `it{ is_expected.to raise_error }` fails. It fails because `StandardError` is raised and is not rescued by the `raise_error` matcher.

So can I use blocks with `is_expected`? Or am I destined to write `specify{ expect{ subject }` over and over and over again? Will rspec be supporting blocks for use with `is_expected` in the future?

Answer (score 3):

Per [the documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax), `is_expected` is simply equivalent to `expect(subject)`. The `StandardError` you are getting is being raised by the evaluation of the `subject` parameter to `is_expected`. The matcher is never invoked.

It doesn't make sense for `is_expected` to take a block, since its purpose to implicitly operate on `subject`. However, if `subject` is defined to be a `Proc` or `Lambda`, then it does just what you'd expect it to do, as in the following:

```
describe 'foo' do
  subject{ Proc.new { foo } }
  specify{ expect{ subject.call }.to raise_error }
  it{ is_expected.to raise_error }
end
```

Comment: Newer syntax: `subject { proc { foo } }`   ([rubocop](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/Proc))